# Accessing a variable's name

Tags: python, variables

I'm trying to access a variable's name.  For example, if I call a function to print a list (`printL`)
and want to print my list's name `"A_minus_B"`:

```
def printL (xlist):
    print "****************************"
    print "name of list"
    print (" entries :  "),len(xlist) 
    print xlist
    print  "****************************"
    return()
```

How can I get the function to print `"A_minus_B"` instead of `"name of list"`, the name I used when calling the function `printL(A_minus_B)`?

Comment: It will help if you tell us what language you're using.

Comment: Sorry. This is for Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can't.<sup>*</sup> The detailed reasons are discussed in the [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding), but basically what Python does when you call `printL(A_minus_B)` is take the value that has been labeled `A_minus_B` and create a new label, `xlist`, that happens to refer to the same thing. From that point on, the label `xlist` has absolutely no connection to the other label `A_minus_B`, and in fact, the value which has been labeled `A_minus_B` or `xlist` or whatever has no connection to any of the names that have been used to label it.

---

<sup>*</sup>Well, you *can*, by using some deep "Python voodoo"... you would basically have to tell Python to read the piece of source code where you call `printL(A_minus_B)` and extract the variable name from there. Normally that's the kind of thing you probably shouldn't be doing (not because you're a beginner, but because it usually indicates you've designed your program the wrong way), but debugging is one of those cases where it's probably appropriate. Here's one way to do it:

```
import inspect, pprint

def print_values(*names):
    caller = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    for name in names:
        if name in caller.f_locals:
            value = caller.f_locals[name]
        elif name in caller.f_globals:
            value = caller.f_globals[name]
        else:
            print 'no such variable: ' + name
        # do whatever you want with name and value, for example:
        print "****************************"
        print name
        print (" entries :  "),len(value) 
        print value
        print  "****************************"
```

The catch is that when you call this function, you have to pass it the *name* of the variable you want printed, not the variable itself. So you would call `print_values('A_minus_B')`, not `print_values(A_minus_B)`. You can pass multiple names to have them all printed out, for example `print_values('A_minus_B', 'C_minus_D', 'foo')`.

Comment: thanks David. How should I design this type of thing then? "When calling a function, tell me the name of the parameter I passed to that function". I suppose I could do listDic = {"listA" : list_A, "listB" : list_A} then call printL(listDic(mylist)), and have printL display mylist.  Is this bad design?

Comment: It depends, why do you need the name of the variable?

Comment: I have a function to print values of my lists (soe sort of debugging) and want to print out the name of the list I had passed to the function. The dictionnary approach seems to work. I have a listDic = {"list_A": listA, "list_B": listB}  I call printL("listX"), which print "listX" then print the values in listX by doing print listDic[listX]. Is this sound coding? Many thanks Thomas

Comment: (I'm doing this here because in the question that was linked as a duplicate in heltonbiker's comment, this would not be a good design choice.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to do it:

```
list_dict = {}     #creates empty dictionary
list_dict['list_a'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]   # here you create the name (key)
nice_name = 'list_b'
list_dict[nice_name] = [7,8,9,10,11,12]   # here you use already existing string as name (key)

def list_info(ld):
    for key in sorted(ld):
        print "****************************"
        print key
        print " entries :  " ,len(ld[key]) 
        print ld[key]
        print  "****************************"

list_info(list_dict)
```